# Subquery in select Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

My query is as below

```
var result = from cr in cumulativeresult
    orderby cr.Days
    select new
    {
        Days = cr.Days,
        Com = (from cr1 in cumulativeresult
            where cr1.Days < cr.Days
            group cr1 by 1 into cr1grp
            select
            new
            {
                Count = cr1grp.Count() + cr.Com 
            }),
        ComPercent = Math.Round((double.Parse((
            from cr1 in cumulativeresult
            where cr1.Days < cr.Days
            group cr1 by 1 into cr1grp 
            select cr1grp.Count() + cr.Com).ToString()) / ComCount) * 100, 2)
    };
```

But the Com and ComPercent are not coming as values. How will I be able to retrieve the value within them? My loop for retrieving them is as follows

**Update**

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(item.Days, item.Com, item.ComPercent);
}
```

I do not want to do any processing on my foreach loop, I want the value in my linq query itself.

Comment: what do u mean by "not coming as number"?u  are using toString()

Comment: I want value in my output, current it is coming as a type

Comment: yes, u are not accessing ur output correctly

Comment: "I do not want to do any processing on my foreach loop," what processing? u need to iterate over your result

Comment: @Hitesh as posted, `Com` may contains multiple 'counts', how would you expect them to be displayed in a column??

Comment: no it wont, I have written group by 1 and the output is Count(), so it would give only 1 result. However, I am ok if Take(1) is done on the subquery result

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the *group by 1* part. See my answer below for a possible solution. Side note: Please use *@har07* if you want me to get notified about your comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compiler doesn't know your subquery will always return one row, since the return type is still `IEnumerable` (or `IQueryable`). This can be solved by using `First()` or `Single()` (or the corresponding `..OrDefault()` version), however, it is more common to just use `Count()` without grouping, for example :

```
Com = (from cr1 in cumulativeresult
       where cr1.Days < cr.Days
       select cr1
      ).Count() + cr.Com,
```

You might also want to consider moving the subquery into a `let` clause, so it can be reused to calculate `Com` and `ComPercent` :

```
var result = from cr in cumulativeresult
             let totalCount = 
                      (from cr1 in cumulativeresult
                       where cr1.Days < cr.Days
                       select cr1
                      ).Count() + cr.Com 
             orderby cr.Days
             select new
             {
                Days = cr.Days,
                Com = totalCount,
                ComPercent = Math.Round((double)totalCount / ComCount * 100, 2)
             };
```

Comment: Calling .Count() is so much easier than using a "group" clause and then calling ".Single()".  The T-SQL statement that is generated is also simpler. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you need to select the `.First` of what you, but not Linq, knows is a single grouping of `1`.

I've adjusted your query in a couple of other ways as well:

1. To get some output I had to change the `<` to `<=`.
2. I used a cast instead of reparsing as double.

This is the whole LinqPad query:

```
var cumulativeresult = new[] { new { Days = 0, Com = 0 }, new { Days = 1, Com = 1 } };
var ComCount = cumulativeresult.Count();
var result = from cr in cumulativeresult
             orderby cr.Days
             select new
             {
                 Days = cr.Days,
                 Com = (from cr1 in cumulativeresult
                        where cr1.Days <= cr.Days
                        group cr1 by 1 into cr1grp
                        select
                          new
                          {
                              Count = cr1grp.Count() + cr.Com
                          }
                           ).First().Count,
                 ComPercent = Math.Round((//double.Parse(
                           ((double)(
                           from cr1 in cumulativeresult
                           where cr1.Days <= cr.Days
                           group cr1 by 1 into cr1grp
                           select cr1grp.Count() + cr.Com).First())//.ToString())
                           / ComCount) * 100, 2
                           )
             };

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new[] {new DataColumn("Days"),new DataColumn("Com"),new DataColumn("ComPercent")  });
foreach (var item in result)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(item.Days, item.Com, item.ComPercent);
}
dt.Dump();
```